# Can the electric field of a point on a charge distribution be calculated? Specifically the electric field of a point charge on a line of charge

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

> "A uniform line of charge with length 20.0 cm is along the x-axis, with its midpoint at x=0. Its charge per length is +4.80 nC/m. A small sphere with charge -2.00 micro coulombs is located at x=0,y=5.00 cm. What are the magnitude and direction of the force that the charged sphere exerts on the line of charge?"

So before I get into what confused me about this problem let me show you how I solved it. I calculated the electric field from the line of charge at the center of the sphere, by deriving the following formula $$\vec{E}_{Q on Sphere}=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{Q}{y\sqrt{\frac{L^2}{4}+y^2}}\hat{j}$$ where Q is the total charge along the line of charge, L is the length of the line of charge and y is the distance of the sphere from the line of charge, along the y-axis. I then calculated the electric field by plugging the appropriate values of L and y given in the problem and I calculated Q by multiplying the charge density by the length L. Then to get the force the line of charge exerts on the sphere I used the formula, $$\vec{F}_{Q on Sphere}=q\vec{E}_{Q on Sphere}$$ Lastly I applied newton's third law, which tells me that $$\vec{F}_{Sphere on Q}=-\vec{F}_{Q on Sphere}$$ and then I had my answer. I was wondering though is it possible to calculate the electric field of the sphere on the line of charge, $\vec{E}_{Sphere on Q}$, directly. This calculation seems very different to me and the fact I couldn't calculate this was why the problem originally stumped me. The reason why is because it doesn't seem like you can set up an integral in the same way you do to derive $\vec{E}_{Q on Sphere}$ above. To show you what I mean let me show you how I set up the integral to find $\vec{E}_{Q on Sphere}$. When I derived my integral to get  $\vec{E}_{Q on Sphere}$ above I expressed the electric field from an infinitesimally small unit of charge as $$dE_{Q on Sphere}=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{dQ}{x^2+y^2}$$ From here it is easy to see how this can be turned into an integral because $dQ=\lambda dx$, where $\lambda$ is the charge density. So to get the electric field, we integrate with respect to x. We can also ignore the x-component of the electric field by symmetry so, we have $$E_{Q on Sphere}=\int dE_{(Q on Sphere) y}=\int dE_{Q on Sphere}sin \theta$$ With some basic trigonometry we see that $$sin \theta=\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$ Putting all this together we get the following integral, $$E_{Q on Sphere}=\frac{\lambda}{4\pi \epsilon_0}\int_{-L/2}^{L/2}\frac{y}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}dx$$ Now I'll try to derive the electric field of the sphere on the line of charge. I'll start by writing out the equation for electric field at an arbitrary point on the line of charge. $$E_{Sphere on Q}=\frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0}\frac{q}{x^2+y^2}$$ Now this is where I got stuck. The problem I have with this expression is I see no way to integrate because there is nothing you can use to relate to a differential such as dx. Am I just taking the wrong approach here, or is calculating this electric field directly not possible?

Comment: Your question is very difficult to read. I'll try to format it for you but I suggest reading up the formatting guide of this site. I tried to make a quick fix, but I suggest you try to narrow the post down to : 1. The problem statement, 2. The doubt you had, 3. the attempts you tried to solve it

Comment: Please consider asking what concept you didn't understand instead of asking how to solve a specific question. This will help you in the future, so that by understanding the concept, you can solve such type of questions yourself

Comment: Thanks Buraian. I'll try to shorten the problem and only keep the bare essentials in my question for clarity.

Comment: Okay I updated my question and I tried to shorten it but it ended up being longer because I went more in depth with my math. Hopefully it is more clear and easier to read though.

Comment: Much much better than when I first saw it! Good job and +1

Comment: Thanks for the kind words. I didn't know at first how to write up my equations in latex for this but once I got the hang of it, it was easier to formulate my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't calculate the electric field "on the line of charge". Or on anything. The field exists at the location of the line of charge. At any point on line of charge you have an electric field produced by the sphere. This is E and not dE. What you sum are the forces on each piece of the line of charge. You have to calculate dF=Edq and sum these contributions. But pay attention to direction of each dF. They are vectors. Calculate component along the line and perpendicular to the line separately.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. The language I used probably isn't the best. What I meant to say is can we find the sum of all electric field vectors, E, at each point along the line of charge? I don't think it is possible doing calculus but I realize now you don't need to. You can just calculate the force directly using coulomb's law and the same differential, dQ, used to calculate the other electric field.

Comment: I edited out the dE at the end and replaced it with E.

Comment: Adding all the electric field vectors the way you describe is meaningless. For one thing, you would add an infinite number of finite vectors. This is not finite. And second, what would be the meaning of adding electric fields at different points?

Comment: I don't know. I guess I just assumed that if I could add up an infinite number of forces at different points and get a finite number the corresponding electric fields would have to converge to a finite number as well, in order for the Lorentz force formula to hold for stationary charges. But now that I think about it, that's clearly wrong. The electric field exists at the line of charge but you can't represent that as one vector. At each point it will be different but we are only concerned with how each vector effects the charge dQ.